# Como usar a biblioteca ksoap2

Tags: android, soap

Estou com a seguinte situação, tenho um servidor em PHP:

```
class Teste {
    function obtemStatus(){ 
        return 'ok'; 
    }
}

$server = new SoapServer(null, array('uri'=>'http://test-uri/'));
$server->setClass('Teste');
$server->handle();
```

E um cliente em PHP também:

```
$options = array(
    'location'  => 'http://localhost/android/server/index.php',
    'uri'       => 'http://test-uri/'
);
$client = new SoapClient(null, $options);
echo $client->obtemStatus();
```

Isso está funcionando perfeitamente, mas agora quero utilizar esse serviço pelo Anndroid, tenho o seguinte código:

```
private String NAMESPACE = "urn://http://localhost";
private String METHOD_NAME = "obtemStatus";
private String URL = "localhost/android/client/index.php";
private String SOAP_ACTION = "localhost/android/client/index.php/obtemStatus";

// observação: antes do localhost está o http:// mas tive que tirar para postar aqui
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

SoapObject soap = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soap);

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

try {
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Está dando o seguinte erro:

```
09-22 20:59:27.501    9637-9637/com.anderson.soap D/HyLog﹕ I : /data/font/config/dfactpre.dat, No such file or directory (2)
09-22 20:59:27.661    9637-9637/com.anderson.soap D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-22 20:59:27.661    9637-9637/com.anderson.soap E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.anderson.soap, PID: 9637
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.anderson.soap/com.anderson.soap.MyActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2202)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1148)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:251)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:229)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
            at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.openOutputStream(ServiceConnectionSE.java:120)
            at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:176)
            at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:114)
            at com.anderson.soap.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:39)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
```

Alguém sabe oque pode ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anderson, esse erro que deu não é diretamente com seu código de conexão. Esse erro é devido ao local onde está executando uma conexão com a internet, na `MainThread`.

Não é recomendado realizar operações de rede ou *I/O* (algumas são permitidas, SharedPreferences por exemplo) em geral na `MainThread`.

A `MainThread` é responsável por muitas operações essenciais (desenho de View, tratamento de eventos, criação e destruição de `Activities`, `Fragments` e outras entidades, operações de salvamento de estado da `Activity`, `Fragment` e hierarquia de `Views`), logo não é bom interromper a `MainThread`.

Para saber mais sobre a `Main Thread`, dê uma olhada em [A journey on the Android Main Thread](http://corner.squareup.com/2013/10/android-main-thread-1.html)

Muitas vezes é por causa de muito processamento lento na `MainThread` que se vê aquele *Dialog*  de `ANR`.

[image: Dialog de ANR]

Para isso é recomendado que inicie um [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) para executar processamentos de rede e *I/O*.

A `AsyncTask` abstrai o uso de `Threads` e a comunicação com a `MainThread`. No fundo seu código irá rodar em uma `Thread` separada (método `doInBackground`), mas em alguns momentos (`onPreExecute` e `onPostExecute`) o código será executado na `Main Thread`.

É possível também publicar um progresso, para atualizar a interface. Para isso use o método `publishProgress` dentro do `doInBackground`. Com isso o método `onProgressUpdate` será executado na `MainThread`.

Além disso, a `AsyncTask` é altamente parametrizada: `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`, logo você pode especificar um tipo para cada valor que é usado nela. Caso ela seja uma `AsyncTask` apenas para processamento em *Background*, o mais comum é usar `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>`.

Para mais detalhes dê uma olhada em [Keeping Your App Responsive](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html) e [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Usando `AsyncTask`, seu código ficaria:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Todo codigo executado nesse metodo sera feito em um Thread
            // Fora da MainThread.
            // Nao atualize elementos de interface (Views) aqui!

            SoapObject soap = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soap);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            try {
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Nao ha nenhum resultado no processamento, nao retorno nada.
            // Voce pode retornar algo se achar necessario
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Esse metodo é executado na MainThread!
            // O "result" é o retorno do metodo doInBackground
            // Atualize elementos de interface aqui.
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Esse é o básico de `AsyncTask`, para mais detalhes eu recomendo ver alguns tutoriais do Android, especificamente o [Connecting to the Network](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html).

Quando estiver com mais tempo, dê uma olhada sobre os [`Loaders`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html), eles fazem um processamento em uma `Thread` separada mas são gerenciadas pelo ciclo de vida da `Activity` automaticamente, simplificando muito o trabalho.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, depois vou dar uma lida sobre esse Loaders.
Agora está dando outro erro:
09-23 14:08:51.547  24721-24757/com.anderson.soap W/System.err﹕ java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 80) after 20000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)..

Não sei por que não está conectando no localhost, vi em outros topicos aqui do stackoverflow que falaram para trocar para 127.0.0.1:80 e nada.

Comment: Está testando de dentro do emulador correto? Use o endereço `10.0.2.2` se este for o caso. Mais detalhes sobre os endereços: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses.

Comment: Não, estou testando direto no celular.

Em outro resposta falaram para usar o 10.0.2.2:8080, mas da o erro: SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8080) after 20000ms

Comment: Então esse é o erro, `localhost` do celular é ele mesmo, se seu servidor está na sua máquina de trabalho, você deve verificar o endereço dela na rede (supondo que o celular e o servidor estão na mesma rede).

Comment: É verdade, que mancada minha. ;/

Coloquei meu o ip da maquina aqui e passou, mas parou em outro erro:

org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Expected a quoted string (position:DOCDECL @1:50 in java.io.InputStreamReader@65988fc0)

Vi em outros topicos que o pessoal falou para usar isso List<HeaderProperty> headers = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>(); mas não adiantou. Meu servidor não possui wsdl será que isso tem haver?

Comment: Acho que já eu já sei oque pode ser, tentei acessar http://172.16.6.170/ pelo navegador e deu erro de permissão. deve ser isso

Comment: É realmente eu estava com problema de permissão no servidor, já está resolvido, agora já consigo ver o retorno, mas ainda está com erro:

org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT ok@1:3 in java.io.InputStreamReader@65988e28)
Aquele "ok" é o retorno.

Comment: Não sei bem o protocolo SOAP, o `response` está apenas "ok"? Não deveria estar com o envelope?

Comment: O retorno está assim:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://test-uri/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:obtemStatusResponse>
   <return xsi:type="xsd:string">ok</return>
  </ns1:obtemStatusResponse>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Comment: Cara, não sei direito oque aconteceu mas está funcionado..
Algumas lições aprendidas:
 - Usar a classe AsyncTask
 - Verificar o IP
 - Verificar a permissão no servidor


Valeu muito Obrigado de novo! kkk

Comment: Muito bom, infelizmente não pude ajudar tanto com o `SOAP`, como disse nunca usei ele de fato. Bom trabalho.