# Como obter resultado de uma tarefa assíncrona no Android?

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando resgatar o valor da minha API utilizando `.get()` mas está sempre caindo em Exception, acredito que não estou fazendo corretamente.

```
private static String APIAddress = "http://10.0.2.2/APIs/LOGINServer/server.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String response = null;
        try {
            response = new APIConnect().execute(APIAddress).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i("SERVER RESPONSE", response);
    }

    public class APIConnect extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String content;

            content = System.APIRequest(APIAddress);
            Log.i("HTTP Server", content);

            return content;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Raphael, não recomendo chamar o método `get` da `AsyncTask` dentro do `onCreate`. O método `get` vai bloquear a `Main Thread` à espera do resultado, o que vai causar uma péssima experiência para o usuário se essa tarefa demorar. Dessa forma irá travar seu app, com aquela tela preta, até o término da sua tarefa. Recomendo usar o método `onPostExecute` para atualizar a UI.

Comment: Como seria neste caso?
Eu preciso que o conteúdo retornado por `System.APIRequest(APIAddress)` possa ser acessível.

Comment: Como você fez sua `APIConnect` como uma classe interna da `Activity` e não estática, a `APIConnect` possui implicitamente uma referência para a `Activity`, logo é só chamar os métodos que atualizam a UI lá no método `onPostExecute`. Se a `APIConnect` fosse externa ou estática, teria que usar algum padrão para atualizar, seja usando `Observer` ou guardando uma referência para a `Activity`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não é recomendado (apesar de ser possível) chamar o método `get` da `AsyncTask` dentro da `Main Thread`, porque além de bloquear uma tarefa que deveria ser assíncrona ela causa uma experiência ruim para o usuário.

Com a `Main Thread` bloqueada no `onCreate`, o usuário ficará vendo aquela tela preta até que a tarefa termine, com o risco de se ter um *ANR*.

Poderá ver mais detalhes sobre isso nessa minha resposta: [Como usar a biblioteca ksoap2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33509/como-usar-a-biblioteca-ksoap2/33514#33514).

---

**A melhor forma que considero para esse tipo de uso, é usando `Loaders`.**

Os `Loaders` surgiram na API 11 (Android 3.0) como uma adaptação da API de `AsyncTask` para o ciclo de vida tanto dos `Fragments` quanto da `Activity`.

Para versões anteriores à API 11, você pode utilizar a `Support Library v4` que ela faz a compatibilidade, bastando extender `FragmentActivity`.

Isso significa que o `Loader` é altamente relacionado com o ciclo de vida da `Activity` ou do `Fragment`, e a sua gerência é feita automaticamente pelo `LoaderManager`.

Um detalhe importante para considerar o uso é que na primeira vez que criar o `Loader` ele irá executar o processamento. Mas caso a `Activity` venha a ser destruída, não importa se o processamento acabou ou não, ele irá atualizar sempre a `Activity` correta. Isso significa que na segunda `Activity` o `LoaderManager` irá reutilizar o `Loader` anterior evitando o processamento desnecessário.

Para usar um `Loader`, irei considerar o uso da `Support Library`, mas as chamadas são parecidas.

Classe `APIConnectLoader`

```
public class APIConnectLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<String> {

    String mResult;
    String mAPIAddress;

    public APIConnectLoader(Context context, String APIAddress) {
        super(context);
        mAPIAddress = APIAddress;
    }

    /****************************************************/
    /** (1) A task that performs the asynchronous load **/
    /****************************************************/
    @Override
    public String loadInBackground() {
        return System.APIRequest(mAPIAddress);
    }

    /********************************************************/
    /** (2) Deliver the results to the registered listener **/
    /********************************************************/
    @Override
    public void deliverResult(String data) {
        if(isReset()) {
            releaseResources(data);
            return;
        }

        String oldData = mResult;
        mResult = data;

        if(isStarted()) {
            super.deliverResult(data);
        }

        if(oldData != null && oldData != data) {
            releaseResources(oldData);
        }
    }

    /*********************************************************/
    /** (3) Implement the Loader’s state-dependent behavior **/
    /*********************************************************/
    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        if(mResult != null) {
            deliverResult(mResult);
        }

        if (takeContentChanged() || mResult == null) {
            // When the observer detects a change, it should call onContentChanged()
            // on the Loader, which will cause the next call to takeContentChanged()
            // to return true. If this is ever the case (or if the current data is
            // null), we force a new load.
            forceLoad();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stopLoading() {
        // Attempt to cancel the current load task if possible.
        cancelLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCanceled(String data) {
        releaseResources(data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReset() {
        super.onReset();

        onStopLoading();

        releaseResources(mResult);
        mResult = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStopLoading() {
        cancelLoad();
    }

    protected void releaseResources(String data) {
        // For a simple List, there is nothing to do. For something like a Cursor, we
        // would close it in this method. All resources associated with the Loader
        // should be released here.
    }

    public void refresh() {
        mResult = null;
        onContentChanged();
    }
}
```

Classe `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String> {

    private static String APIAddress = "http://10.0.2.2/APIs/LOGINServer/server.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Inicia o Loader, ou recupera o Loader anterior caso exista
        // O LoaderManager eh quem ira verificar a existencia de um Loader
        // anterior
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(ID_DO_LOADER, null, this);
        // Se nao usar o Support Library use o getLoaderManager ao inves
        // do getSupportLoaderManager
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<String> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        // Instancia o AsyncTaskLoader
        return new APIConnectLoader(APIAddress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<String> loader, String data) {
        // Atualizar UI de acordo com o resultado (data)
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<String> loader) {
        // Nao precisa fazer nada no caso de uma String,
        // Se fosse um cursor, teria que limpar recursos
        // referentes ao cursor anterior
    }
}
```

---

Como você fez sua `APIConnect` como uma classe interna da `Activity` e não estática, a `APIConnect` possui implicitamente uma referência para a `Activity`, logo é só chamar os métodos que atualizam a UI lá no método `onPostExecute`.

Se a `APIConnect` fosse externa ou estática, teria que usar algum padrão para atualizar, seja usando `Observer` ou guardando uma referência para a `Activity`.

No seu caso, um esboço seria:

```
public class APIConnect extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String content;

        content = System.APIRequest(APIAddress);
        Log.i("HTTP Server", content);

        return content;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // Nesse momento podemos atualizar a UI,
        // porque esse código esta sendo executado
        // na Main Thread.
        setTextInActivity(result);
        // result é o valor de content do doInBackground
    }
}
```

O método `setTextInActivity` pode ser declarado na sua `Activity`, que o `APIConnect` terá acesso.

---

Usando uma `Inner Class` a `AsyncTask` possui uma referência implícita para a `Activity`, o que é ruim pensando no ciclo de vida da `Activity`, o que ocasiona um **Memory Leak** e dado que a `Activity` é um objeto muito grande, pode causas problemas a longo prazo.

O **Memory Leak** é causado da seguinte forma:

1. Uma `AsyncTask` é iniciada (tendo a referência implícita para a `Activity`).
2. Nesse meio tempo, antes do término da `AsyncTask`, a `Activity` é destruída. Gerando uma nova `Activity`.
3. Enquanto a `AsyncTask` não terminar, a `Activity` destruída não será coletada pelo `Garbage Collector`, mantendo um objeto pesado e desnecessário na memória. E  além disso, quando a `AsyncTask` terminar, a antiga `Activity` é quem será atualizada, podendo causar diversos erros, dado que ela já foi destruída.

Uma solução simples seria criar uma subclasse da `AsyncTask` externa e usar o padrão `Observer` para atualizar a `UI`. Lembrando de cancelar a `AsyncTask` e remover a referência do `Listener` quando a `Activity` for destruída.

Classe `APIConnect`

```
public class APIConnect extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private APIConnectListener mListener;
    // doInBackground continua o mesmo.

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(mListener != null) {
            mListener.updateUI(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled () {
        // Cancelar tudo que estiver fazendo.
        // Remover a referência para o Listener, a fim de evitar memory leak
        mListener = null;
    }

    // Getter e Setter do Listener

    // Definicao da interface Observer
    public static interface APIConnectListener {
        public void updateUI(String result);
    }
}
```

Classe `Activity`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements APIConnect.APIConnectListener {

    private static String APIAddress = "http://10.0.2.2/APIs/LOGINServer/server.php";
    APIConnect mAPIConnect;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mAPIConnect = new APIConnect();
        mAPIConnect.setAPIConnectListener(this);

        mAPIConnect.execute(APIAddress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Cancela a AsyncTask e limpa a referência
        mAPIConnect.cancel();
        mAPIConnect = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUI(String result) {
        // Atualiza a UI com o resultado da APIConnect
    }
}
```

Referências:

1. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html
2. http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html

Comment: `String result = new APIConnect().execute()` Desta forma eu acesso o valor result?

Comment: Sim, o `get` vai retornar o mesmo que o método `doInBackground`. Mas isso vai travar sua interface durante a execução.

Comment: Poderia me informar se manter a minha classe APIConnect fora da classe interna da Activity e estática é uma forma melhor?

Comment: @RaphaelCastro, sim, manter fora é melhor (acredito que a melhor razão seja evitar `Memory Leaks`) e só precisa usar um `Listener` para notificar a `Activity` que o processamento terminou. Posso incluir isso em minha resposta daqui a pouco.