# Erro NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android

Pessoal esta dando esse `exception` porque pelo que pesquisei, a partir do Android 3.0 não se pode mais fazer chamada de rede em uma Activity, mas eu preciso que isso seja feito:

Vejam minha classe de leitura de Rssfeed :

```
public class XmlReader {

    private String rssUrl;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public XmlReader(String rssUrl) {
        this.rssUrl = rssUrl;

    }

    /**
     * Pega uma lista de XML.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public List<Segmento> getItems() throws Exception {
        // SAX parse RSS data
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
        XmlParseHandler handler = new XmlParseHandler();
        saxParser.parse(rssUrl, handler);
        return handler.getItems();
    }

}
```

Estou chamando ela na `View` assim:

```
RssReader reader = new RssReader("endereco.xml");
```

Isso precisa ser feito, porem da o erro

> android.iosNetworkOnMainThreadException

.
Eu vi que a solução era usar AsyncTask, porem não entendi pelo menos como aplicar no meu modelo, como ficaria a implementação e a chamada?

Comment: Vê se essa pergunta/resposta não ajuda a resolver o problema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33509/como-usar-a-biblioteca-ksoap2/33514#33514

Answer (score 2):

Esta exceção ocorre, como disse muito bem, quando se tenta fazer uma operação sobre a rede na *Thread* principal. Tens de correr o teu código numa [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

```
class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, RssReader> {

    private Exception exception;

    protected RssReader doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            SAXParserFactory factory =SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser=factory.newSAXParser();
            XmlParseHandler handler = new XmlParseHandler();
            saxParser.parse(urls[0], handler);
            saveInBD(handler.getItems());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.exception = e;
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(RssReader reader) {

    }
}
```

Em vez de

```
RssReader reader = new RssReader("endereco.xml");
```

executar a tarefa:

```
new RetrieveFeedTask().execute(urlToRssFeed);
```

Não esquecer de adicionar ao `AndroidManifest.xml` isto:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

[<sup>Fonte SOen</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/1817673)

[Exemplo](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.pt/p/android-sax-parser.html)

Comment: Eu ja tinha visto essa solução nao consegui aplicar no meu modelo, 1 - pq preciso do metodo getItem e a forma q ta no exemplo ele esta sumindo 2 - da varios erros, na 1 linha manda criar a classe Rssfeed, e la em baixo não encontra a rssUrl, que no meu caso tem q ser passado no construtor, sera que pode dizer como fica exatamente no meu modelo?

Comment: Eu preciso do metodo, pq tenho que buscar algumas informações dele, Ex RssReader  reader = new RssReader("xxxxx");  então depois de carregar a url preciso buscar o 1 elemento reader.getItem().get(0).getId();   , usando esse asyncTask não vou poder criar o objeto pra acessar, e ai como faço?

Comment: Quando der ajudo, agora estou estou sem tempo.

Comment: War o melhor seria mesmo guardar os dados num Banco de dados quando os lês porque fica complicado ir buscar os dados a um AsyncTask.

Comment: Vê também o exemplo que pus.

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema, apenas implementei isso no metodo onCreate e rodou normalmente

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```