# Prioridade em progressdialog

Tags: java, android

É possível priorizar um `progressdialog` diante a uma `Thread`?
Em meu app, após clicar em um botão, preciso congelar um `progressdialog` por 2 segundos. Após isso, gerar uma consulta ao meu `webservice`, e assim que retornar os dados, eles são apresentados em um `alertdialog`,que após aberto, faz o `progressdialog` receber o `dismiss()` para fechá-lo. Porém, mesmo instanciando uma nova `Thread` e setando o `sleep()` ou `wait()`, o processo apenas congela a `Thread` por inteira e não apresenta o `progressdialog`. Na tela, primeiramente o alert é gerado e o progress fica em segundo plano até o alert ser fechado.

Existe uma maneira possível de gerar na sequencia primeiramente o Progress com 2 segundos de freeze e depois o alert dialog?
Segue trecho do código.

```
    final EditText Nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cmdDigDe);
    Button btnConDeE = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConDe);
    btnConDeE.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DemE.this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Listando medicamentos");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Buscando...");
            progressDialog.show();

                String nomeProduto = Nome.getText().toString();
                String laboratorio = null;
                String aliquota = "17";

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                }

                if (nomeProduto == "") {
                    Toast.makeText(DemE.this, "Por favor digite o nome do medicamento", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else

                    try {
                        URL url = new URL("http");
                        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
                        con.setDoOutput(true);
                        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());

                        writer.write("nome=" + nomeProduto + "&aliquota=" + aliquota + (laboratorio != null ? "&laboratorio=" + laboratorio : ""));
                        writer.flush();

                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                        String result = "";
                        String line;


                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                            result += line;

                            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
                            tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(result));

                            final String text = tv.getText().toString();


                            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
                            alertDialog.setTitle("Medicamentos:");
                            alertDialog.setMessage(text);
                            alertDialog.setButton("Voltar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            alertDialog.show();


                        }

                        writer.close();
                        reader.close();

                    }
```

Comment: Diego, não entendi onde está usando `Thread` neste código. Além disso usar `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll()` não inicia uma nova `Thread` e é uma má prática, porque mascara alguns problemas. Esse código está executando na `MainThread` e consequentemente travando a interface, recomendo dar uma olhada nessa pergunta para resolver isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33509/como-usar-a-biblioteca-ksoap2/33514#33514.

Comment: Wakim, na verdade acabei postando o código antigo, desculpe, se eu instanciar uma nova thread, existe uma maneira de colocar em espera o progressdialog para executar em tela e freezar os 2 segundos? Ou colocar em espera o proprio alertdialog,  por exemplo .. o código executa o progressdialog e apresenta em tela, depois instancia uma nova thread, coloca essa thread em espera por 2 segundos, e após isso executa o alertdialog apresentando as informações retornadas pela URL. Existe uma maneira de adaptar o código para executar dessa maneira?

Comment: Sim é possível, mas eu recomendo uma outra abordagem. Exibir um `DialogFragment` (usando `cancelable` como `false`) e iniciar uma `AsyncTask` no `onViewCreated`, atualizando-a ao final do processamento no método `onPostExecute`.

Comment: Vou testar aqui agora! Muito obrigado.

Comment: Você pode tentar realizar o processo de busca de dados em outra thread,por exemplo só quando a thread terminasse sua execução vc chamaria o demiss do alertDialog... embora talvez nao seja a melhor solução..

Answer (score 1):

Diego, vejo algumas coisas estranhas no seu código, por exemplo, você está chamando o método `AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();` dentro do loop (`while`). Segundo, você está executando um processo que pode demorar dentro da Thread principal.

Você poderia usar um `AsyncTask`, então no método `onPreExecute`, você inicia seu `ProgressDialog`, no método `doInBackground` você faz sua chamada Http e no método `onPostExecute`, você finaliza seu `ProgressDialog` e exibe seu `AlertDialog`.

Leia mais sobre [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 1):

O certo é fazer isso usando uma AsyncTask

-Sua activity ficaria assim:

```
public class DemE extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    //Suponho que seja aqui aonde você roda o metodo
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        findViewById(R.id.btnConDe).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String nomeProduto =  findViewById(R.id.cmdDigDe).getText().toString();
        String laboratorio = null;
        String aliquota = "17";


        if (nomeProduto == "") 
            Toast.makeText(DemE.this, "Por favor digite o nome do medicamento", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            new BuscaMedicamentosAsync(this).execute(
                new StringBuilder("nome=")
                        .append(nomeProduto)
                        .append("&aliquota=")
                        .append(aliquota)
                        .append("&laboratorio=")
                        .append(laboratorio == null? "" : laboratorio));
    }
}
```

-E o processamento fica por conta da async:

```
public final class BuscaMedicamentosAsync extends AsyncTask<CharSequence, Integer, CharSequence>
{
    private final AlertDialog alertDialog;
    private final ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public BuscaMedicamentosAsync(Context contexto)
    {
        this.alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(contexto).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Medicamentos:");
        alertDialog.setButton(0, "Voltar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(contexto);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Listando medicamentos");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Buscando...");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false); //Impedir que o usuario feche o dialogo
    }

    @Override
    protected CharSequence doInBackground(CharSequence... parametros)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http");
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());

            writer.write(parametros[0].toString());
            writer.flush();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String line;


            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                result.append(line);
            }

            writer.close();
            reader.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Trata a exceção
        }

        return Html.fromHtml(result.toString()).toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(CharSequence text) {
        super.onPostExecute(text);

        progressDialog.dismiss();

        alertDialog.setMessage(text);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

**Leitura recomendada**

- [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)